# How to keep a screened in porch from leaking

Tags: water, foundation

We recently had a contractor bail on us without finishing the addition to our home.  One of his many misdeeds was our screened in porch.  It is

1. On the second floor - above our new master bathroom
2. Encased floor to ceiling in screens - on two sides
3. The floor has about a 1.5 inch drop over 15 feet from side to side - going TOWARD the house
4. There is no flashing or anything like that

When there is a rainy wind the water collects in a puddle against the house and eventually makes it's way down to the new master bathroom, ruining drywall and other things.

What is the best way to fix this problem - my first guess is to rip up the floors and pour self-leveling compound to level the floor and then install a new subfloor over that with a slight raise on one side to tilt it the opposite direction (away from the house) and then put down new tile or flooring of some kind.

That method seems difficult and error prone.  And expensive.  Does anyone know of any good ways to fix the problem?

Comment: Wow... You're going to need a fourth generation carpenter to answer this.

Comment: I think if you had a contract you need to contact your states contractors board. Sealing so water did not get in would be my first priority, re sloping the floors would be my next project. Depending on the type of decking I would try to salvage the decking (when I hear rip up I think quick demo). 
You may be able to staple up clear plastic sheeting to temporarily block water from entering to reduce the damage to the floor decking and the bedroom below.